# Ref argument is not Classified as a Variable - better fix for this?

Tags: c#

I have this piece of code that was converted from VB.NET.

```
    private static void PrivateExecuteNonQuery(ref Providers enumProvider, ref string statement, ref CommandType commandType, ref ArrayList paramCollection, ref IDbConnection conn, ref Int16 CommandTimeout)
    {
        ExecuteSqlServerNonQuery(ref statement, ref commandType, ref paramCollection, ref (SqlConnection)conn, ref CommandTimeout);
    }
```

I am getting an error because it's saying the ref (SqlConnection)conn is not in the form of a variable so I guess you can't pass in method params for a ref?

So this seems like a hacky solution to me though:

```
    private static void PrivateExecuteNonQuery(ref Providers enumProvider, ref string statement, ref CommandType commandType, ref ArrayList paramCollection, ref IDbConnection conn, ref Int16 CommandTimeout)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = (SqlConnection)conn;

    ExecuteSqlServerNonQuery(ref statement, ref commandType, ref paramCollection, ref sqlConnection, ref CommandTimeout);
    }
```

Anyone know of a better way to satisfy this ref or make this cleaner?

Comment: Just get rid of all the refs....you should not be modifying any of those parameters...

Comment: Is there a reason you're even using `ref` parameters? I'm seeing warning lights, to be honest.

Comment: Doesn't look like you can pass by `ref` and typecast at the same time. I will have to be in two lines but it doesn't look "hacky" at all.

Comment: It may seem "hacky", but that's what VB is doing behind the scenes anyway.

Comment: In your other question (now deleted), and indeed a question from yesterday, you showed the source of the VB version, and all the parameters were `ByVal`. The C# conversion is therefore not pure, as you've introduced `ref`. The question is "why?" Was it intentional or possibly a misunderstanding?

Answer (score 12):

The **purpose** of `ref` is to actually permit the method to modify the contents of a variable passed in by the caller.  If you have **incidental** `ref` parameters, due to conversion from Visual Basic code that used `ByRef` indiscriminately, then you end up in this situation.

You have two choices:

- Remove unnecessary `ref` parameter qualifiers, both in the caller and the callee, or
- Use **real** variables, dummy variables if you have to, as arguments to the method

So, the answer is, no, there is no better way to do it without getting rid of unnecessary `ref` parameter qualifiers.

What is an unnecessary `ref` parameter qualifier?  It is one for a parameter that is never actually **assigned** anywhere in the body of the method.  Most parameters don't need to be `ref` and those that do are usually pretty obvious from inspecting logic of the method.